# How can I save raw bytes into a PNG file?

Tags: c++, png

I have an array of bytes, they are a raw PNG file that was originally a base64 encoded string.

The encoded string:

```
        stEncodedQR = "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";
```

The raw bytes:

```
(src\funcs.cpp:1064) DecodedQRPicture ptr:0x19E51C0 size:0x673
(:0) ---- -----------------------------------------------  ----------------
(:0) 000| 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52  .PNG........IHDR
(:0) 010| 00 00 01 40 00 00 01 40 01 00 00 00 00 E5 EB 98  ...@...@.....ek.
(:0) 020| 07 00 00 06 3A 49 44 41 54 78 DA ED 9A 31 8E AB  ....:IDATxZm.1.+
(:0) 030| 4A 10 45 0B 11 90 D9 1B 40 EA 6D 90 F5 96 F0 06  J.E...Y.@jm.u.p.
(:0) 040| 30 6C 00 6F 89 8C 6D 20 B1 01 C8 08 10 F5 CF 65  0l.o..m 1.H..uOe
(:0) 050| 22 7B 9E F4 7F 40 BF E0 CB D6 48 A3 B1 0F A3 56  "{.t.@?`KVH#1.#V
(:0) 060| 77 D5 AD 5B D5 36 FF 8F 2F FB 82 5F F0 0B 7E C1  wU-[U6../{._p.~A
(:0) 070| 2F F8 05 FF CF E0 62 F6 F4 79 29 CA C7 30 3D 3C  /x..O`bvty)JG0=<
(:0) 080| 1C E6 47 0C FC 59 C7 DD 2C 24 05 57 DF 1F 63 E8  .fG.|YG],$.W_.ch
(:0) 090| DC BB 21 F7 2D 7F 6D 61 1D ED 31 4E CF B1 7C 7A  \;!w-.ma.m1NO1|z
(:0) 0A0| 62 70 28 1B 9B 5B 0B EB B6 5B B1 3F 60 B5 F0 F2  bp(..[.k6[1?`5pr
(:0) 0B0| E1 65 5D 24 07 EB 68 F7 31 6F A3 F7 85 DD 8A FD  ae]$.khw1o#w.].}
(:0) 0C0| BE 4D 75 51 DE FF 0A D8 14 B9 FB 5E 9B DD DD 7B  >MuQ^..X.9{^.]]{
(:0) 0D0| E3 C5 A3 41 FF 20 35 C8 C9 0C 1C 0B 11 61 6C CF  cE#A. 5HI....alO
(:0) 0E0| 73 9B 9E 83 82 82 C5 FE 3E C2 6B 41 E2 F1 31 96  s.....E~>BkAbq1.
(:0) 0F0| 7F FC F9 15 B8 17 83 BC 8E 6A 7E 8D 65 E6 F9 51  .|y.8..<.j~.efyQ
(:0) 100| F1 90 3D 87 7C 89 F3 9F D2 F5 62 90 D0 B3 6A EE  q.=.|.s.Rub.P3jn
(:0) 110| DC 6A 0B E0 8D 4D 66 F9 3A 2A 33 FA 2A 31 18 E7  \j.`.Mfy:*3z*1.g
(:0) 120| A3 28 9F 23 41 31 1F 55 DE 8D D3 7D B0 A6 DA 33  #(.#A1.U^.S}0&Z3
(:0) 130| AD 3A 2D C8 6F A2 6F A9 90 9C FD 3E 5A 23 9C A0  -:-Ho"o)..}>Z#. 
(:0) 140| D8 EB 6A EE 63 5A F0 E0 E4 CF 14 6C 2B 42 72 BF  XkjncZp`dO.l+Br?
(:0) 150| 45 AB 15 8C 73 B7 B1 6D 21 29 B8 54 65 36 70 26  E+..s71m!)8Te6p&
(:0) 160| 46 DE DF F4 D0 DE 54 08 1E E9 38 2F 96 16 3C 8A  F^_tP^T..i8/..<.
(:0) 170| BC 1B 50 9A D0 16 53 C3 7E 0C AC 2E B4 91 B3 B2  <.P.P.SC~.,.4.32
(:0) 180| 6C 4C 0C 1A 22 47 08 A0 7C BE 14 D3 7D 0B 3E D8  lL.."G. |>.S}.>X
(:0) 190| 73 2B 6F 31 6F CD 13 83 FA E9 46 36 A3 BC 0F 88  s+o1oM..ziF6#<..
(:0) 1A0| EE CF 26 CD AB 97 D9 16 92 82 0B B1 B0 51 E2 CC  nO&M+.Y....10QbL
(:0) 1B0| 2A 43 7A D1 00 4E A6 2E F2 B6 40 0C 3C 2D 68 64  *CzQ.N&.r6@.<-hd
(:0) 1C0| 7F 78 6D B3 2B FF A8 F0 96 E9 CD 3D 43 6E 87 90  .xm3+.(p.iM=Cn..
(:0) 1D0| 14 E4 F7 8D E5 0C 94 97 F9 88 14 76 D3 02 8D 37  .dw.e...y..vS..7
(:0) 1E0| BD FB 14 80 8B C1 15 2B E1 EC 90 AF 04 42 25 15  ={...A.+al./.B%.
(:0) 1F0| CC C6 A9 B6 29 DB A6 F7 2C BC 1E F4 01 1F E1 AF  LF)6)[&w,<.t..a/
(:0) 200| 21 3F A2 DD 0C ED E1 AC 76 72 02 B9 5D B7 B4 20  !?"].ma,vr.9]74 
(:0) 210| C1 F8 F2 D2 0A EF 23 8B 9A 5B 8A 3C 92 2F C1 9B  AxrR.o#..[.<./A.
(:0) 220| 78 33 29 B8 C4 09 E7 42 55 6F A8 E4 83 52 DF AA  x3)8D.gBUo(d.R_*
(:0) 230| 7C 75 FC 45 38 52 83 C6 EA F2 C3 10 9B E9 56 4D  |u|E8R.FjrC..iVM
(:0) 240| C4 42 6F DE A2 B8 3C F4 AE B8 97 83 18 D5 CC 31  DBo^"8<t.8...UL1
(:0) 250| AA 67 0C 56 E5 03 17 89 CB F0 BC 8F 96 6D 9E 14  *g.Ve...Kp<..m..
(:0) 260| 3C 8A 70 6E 86 76 E8 EE B2 70 4F 14 28 52 D8 79  <.pn.vhn2pO.(RXy
(:0) 270| 3F 24 05 DD 65 9A B2 91 92 1E 7A BC 33 69 31 90  ?$.]e.2...z<3i1.
(:0) 280| 88 53 1D CB 77 ED B9 1E 5C 87 9F 35 92 EE 2A EF  .S.Kwm9.\..5.n*o
(:0) 290| 2B 4A CF 56 E9 4C C2 12 43 52 10 89 B5 78 2A AE  +JOViLB.CR..5x*.
(:0) 2A0| F4 06 0D E0 64 F0 D1 25 19 69 A9 41 FB 49 F4 D0  t..`dpQ%.i)A{ItP
(:0) 2B0| 4A 65 A9 36 BB 92 80 DA CE DE 0C 9E 18 44 E4 64  Je)6;..ZN^...Ddd
(:0) 2C0| 1B 1F F8 88 28 6B F3 1A 26 1C DC AD C0 C0 A6 05  ..x.(ks.&.\-@@&.
(:0) 2D0| D7 8D CE 8C FA 06 5B 5A CC 17 19 67 CE 84 D0 50  W.N.z.[ZL..gN.PP
(:0) 2E0| 6F 9A 14 3C 0A AB 2B 95 1A E5 E2 40 9B 22 0D 6E  o..<.++..eb@.".n
(:0) 2F0| 0A 79 E7 A5 48 0B BA D3 83 86 D3 41 60 61 E6 36  .yg%H.:S..SA`af6
(:0) 300| 92 FD A1 AF C2 CB 65 DB 93 82 EB 66 34 61 34 67  .}!/BKe[..kf4a4g
(:0) 310| D9 A0 2D 59 C7 FD 3E 90 7F AA F0 0F 4F 0D 22 78  Y -YG}>..*p.O."x
(:0) 320| D2 75 56 67 67 16 D2 8B F7 71 47 F3 96 2A 2D 78  RuVgg.R.wqGs.*-x
(:0) 330| BA 18 AC AB 4E A6 A1 21 DE A8 36 38 29 1A 85 F0  :.,+N&!!^(68)..p
(:0) 340| 61 3E 2E 07 69 4A 5E 58 F5 02 5B 41 16 12 08 F8  a>..iJ^Xu.[A...x
(:0) 350| 38 82 02 1B 95 77 EF D2 7C 39 28 D7 46 E7 AD B2  8....woR|9(WFg-2
(:0) 360| 46 49 9F 5F 3E F3 5C 4D 72 14 A1 7B F7 8F 97 83  FI._>s\Mr.!{w...
(:0) 370| 2E 9F 4E 5C 94 8F B3 1D 6C 6C AF D5 2D ED 19 59  ..N\..3.ll/U-m.Y
(:0) 380| 58 A5 05 0F 4C 84 4D 4F 89 3D D9 80 A1 9B D1 1E  X%..L.MO.=Y.!.Q.
(:0) 390| 7A 14 2B 76 8B 69 41 B4 87 D3 E8 25 00 6A 43 51  z.+v.iA4.Sh%.jCQ
(:0) 3A0| 41 3C 1D 11 F1 C2 D2 56 21 31 A8 0E 58 93 AD E2  A<..qBRV!1(.X.-b
(:0) 3B0| 74 EE 84 E7 98 2F 9A FD 4C D9 67 BA 5E 0C EA F3  tn.g./.}LYg:^.js
(:0) 3C0| 4D A7 E1 43 D9 60 DF C6 FC 28 E4 9A 79 BA 7F B7  M'aCY`_F|(d.y:.7
(:0) 3D0| 5C 97 83 72 CD 8E DE E4 CE AE 98 3C BB 56 8D 8D  \..rM.^dN..<;V..
(:0) 3E0| D5 50 33 2D B8 A2 AC 83 86 97 6D E4 89 5C E1 2F  UP3-8",...md.\a/
(:0) 3F0| E9 DD B1 93 1F 4D C5 E5 E0 A1 FA E6 64 1E 85 85  i]1..MEe`!zfd...
(:0) 400| 8D B9 69 7C 4B 3F 4A 72 F0 81 27 05 D7 91 22 33  .9i|K?Jrp.'.W."3
(:0) 410| 77 23 D2 4E 81 25 F3 24 7B D9 28 A3 B1 7C B8 E6  w#RN.%s${Y(#1|8f
(:0) 420| CB 41 2F 51 1A 04 1E F6 56 E5 3D A9 30 CE 2C F6  KA/Q...vVe=)0N,v
(:0) 430| 3E 96 75 62 D0 A5 79 41 73 4D D7 58 EB 9C 78 95  >.ubP%yAsMWXk.x.
(:0) 440| 52 DC D3 4E 26 06 39 19 F2 DE 6A 4C 04 6B AC 88  R\SN&.9.r^jL.k,.
(:0) 450| 44 4E C9 CE CA 13 92 82 C8 FC 3A 6A BE 25 ED D1  DNINJ...H|:j>%mQ
(:0) 460| 5C 8D EE 44 9E 82 26 69 FD 98 68 5E 0D 3A E1 A0  \.nD..&i}.h^.:a 
(:0) 470| D9 03 45 46 16 E6 A8 66 57 AF 80 E2 FA FB BC E7  Y.EF.f(fW/.bz{<g
(:0) 480| 7A F0 50 29 9B A5 F4 63 79 97 97 44 8D C2 61 41  zpP).%tcy..D.BaA
(:0) 490| B3 AE 2A 2D E8 2A 29 B2 C9 28 3D 6E AE 93 A7 43  3.*-h*)2I(=n..'C
(:0) 4A0| 12 C8 48 0C 5D 5A 70 A1 DB DE 66 3E E9 39 8A CD  .HH.]Zp![^f>i9.M
(:0) 4B0| EE 72 52 B2 6F AB C4 3E A4 05 23 91 48 6B 22 17  nrR2o+D>$.#.Hk".
(:0) 4C0| 49 A1 D3 1C D7 D4 25 60 A3 DA 22 2D 88 6B 5E AA  I!S.WT%`#Z"-.k^*
(:0) 4D0| B3 2F 89 14 9C BC 1B 66 C2 B3 31 55 D7 F7 89 E6  3/...<.fB31UWw.f
(:0) 4E0| F5 E0 A2 FC 43 D7 95 0D 84 A1 8A DB 59 6A D4 30  u`"|CW...!.[YjT0
(:0) 4F0| 7D 4C 3E 2E 07 89 47 DF 9B 6A 6A A2 2E 6A 5E AE  }L>...G_.jj".j^.
(:0) 500| FB A8 FB 38 53 6D 2C A6 05 71 CD D4 93 D6 66 17  {({8Sm,&.qMT.Vf.
(:0) 510| 82 73 9F CF 0E 89 0E D5 DB C4 E0 21 B9 3D 6F 20  .s.O...U[D`!9=o 
(:0) 520| C7 DD 2A 45 25 E6 11 23 F9 18 7F 35 E2 57 83 4B  G]*E%f.#y..5bW.K
(:0) 530| C4 B4 6A 66 5F C7 FC 1C 6B B1 64 82 62 6A 64 AC  D4jf_G|.k1d.bjd,
(:0) 540| 3C 29 88 7F EC 0B DD 0E 51 57 EF 83 8C 55 2F C9  <)..l.].QWo..U/I
(:0) 550| A7 EC E0 6A 13 83 BA FD 23 E7 D0 78 D6 58 AA 29  'l`j..:}#gPxVX*)
(:0) 560| 94 E2 6A F6 F3 31 60 4B 00 E6 6D 35 F7 72 AF 14  .bjvs1`K.fm5wr/.
(:0) 570| F3 F3 86 6A D3 0D E4 13 57 B5 A5 05 35 BE 8D AA  ss.jS.d.W5%.5>.*
(:0) 580| 2D 78 A8 26 DA 39 D8 23 46 E6 25 CE 1F 23 92 CB  -x(&Z9X#Ff%N.#.K
(:0) 590| 41 BC 43 87 E2 6E 08 8F 86 6A BA 9D 38 A7 D7 9A  A<C.bn...j:.8'W.
(:0) 5A0| 7C BC DB 99 CB 41 8D 51 9D ED D1 0D 24 6D E8 8B  |<[.KA.Q.mQ.$mh.
(:0) 5B0| 84 C0 48 46 B6 0A D9 F3 A4 E0 8F F2 FD C4 45 A3  .@HF6.Ys$`.r}DE#
(:0) 5C0| AF 33 D0 99 FD 74 FF BF 26 9A 57 83 BA 6D F6 89  /3P.}t.?&.W.:mv.
(:0) 5D0| A6 1F 0F AB 9B CF 8D 8D 91 A7 63 AB 6A F3 A4 20  &..+.O...'c+js$ 
(:0) 5E0| EF 3D 37 3B BF 52 A1 AF 51 DC CE 39 6E 37 68 1C  o=7;?R!/Q\N9n7h.
(:0) 5F0| F2 E9 9A 2F 07 95 76 34 46 F2 8F 7D 85 B3 90 79  ri./..v4Fr.}.3.y
(:0) 600| 7C 8E A8 82 7A 88 E4 E0 39 6D D2 2D 8D 5A 13 96  |.(.z.d`9mR-.Z..
(:0) 610| B6 DF 4C F3 9E 6E FB 0B A0 AE BB 5B DB 6B 09 7F  6_Ls.n{. .;[[k..
(:0) 620| EE E7 AC EB 16 D3 83 6A FD 71 2E FB 7D 0B BA 83  ng,k.S.j}q.{}.:.
(:0) 630| DD D4 89 A2 3A 1C CE 2B 31 78 7A 0A 8A 8C DD CC  ]T.":.N+1xz...]L
(:0) 640| CF CE 7B 7E 0D 54 DA BC FB 75 35 74 39 F8 FD 76  ON{~.TZ<{u5t9x}v
(:0) 650| D8 17 FC 82 5F F0 0B 7E C1 2F F8 AF AF 7F 00 2C  X.|._p.~A/x//..,
(:0) 660| B0 6E EF BE 03 93 F3 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 AE  0no>..s....IEND.
(:0) 670| 42 60 82                                         B`.
```

But when I try to write a file.png with the raw bytes, it doesn't write anything and the created png is blank. Any ideas how can I work around this?

```
size_t szDecodedLength = 0;
unsigned char * stDecodedQR = base64_decode(encodedPictureBase64,inLenEncodedPicture, &szDecodedLength);
ofstream outPicture("./flash/file.png", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
string outString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(stDecodedQR), szDecodedLength);

if( outPicture && !outPicture.is_open() ){
        return;
    }
    outPicture.write( reinterpret_cast<char*> (stDecodedQR), szDecodedLength);
    
    // outPicture << outString; I've also tried creating a string and doing this but result is the same.
    outPicture.flush();
    outPicture.close();
```

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode

Comment: When you say "it doesn't write anything", do you mean that the size of the resulting file is 0?

Comment: If you write the encoded string without decoding it first the image file will not work. You should still get output, though.

Comment: @AlanBirtles updated the code to show how I'm doing it.

Comment: @jkb Since I'm writing to hardware I'm not really able to see if the size is 0. I can try opening thought and the result is blank. I have other files in the same directory that open just fine.

Comment: @user4581301 I added the decoding part, I decode the string and the resulting bytes are the ones I'm trying to put into my file in binary mode.

Comment: I think you need to know whether your call to `write` is succeeding. Is `write` returning the same value as what's in `szDecodedLength`? And are those values reasonable?

Comment: @jkb write returns a pointer to the object itself as defined in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

Comment: Right. Sorry, conflating another library I'm working with. Do you have a debugger available? Other than trying to display the PNG, do you have a way of inspecting the actual bytes written?

Comment: Not really, since I'm working on an embedded hardware...can't really debug other than  printf...

Answer (score 0):

This code solves the issue, it looks like it might be permission on the device I'm working on. Tested below code in Visual Studio with C++ and it generates the wanted file(picture) correctly, is a QR code that I can scan with my smartphone.

```
size_t szDecodedLength = 0;
unsigned char* stDecodedQR = base64_decode(encodedPictureBase64, inLenEncodedPicture, &szDecodedLength);

const size_t szArr = szDecodedLength;
std::vector<unsigned char> vDecodedQR;
for (auto i = 0; i < szDecodedLength; i++) {
  vDecodedQR.push_back(stDecodedQR[i]);
}

std::ofstream outPicture("mypng.png", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);

if (outPicture && !outPicture.is_open()) {
std::cerr << " Error creating PNG file" << std::endl;
  return;
}

outPicture.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (stDecodedQR), szDecodedLength);
outPicture.close();
```